# Django query on event list: finding most recent events

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a django model that collects events.  It looks roughly like this:

```
class Events(models.Model):
    class EventType(models.TextChoices):
        OPEN = ...
        CLOSE = ...
        OTHER = ...
        READ = ...

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    box = models.ForeignKey(Box, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)
    event_type = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=EventType.choices)
```

Events occur when users do things with boxes.

I have four very related queries I want to do, and I'm not at all sure how to do this without resorting to SQL, which usually isn't the right solution with django.

1. For box B and user U, is the user most recently open or closed for this box?
2. For Box B, how many users are in an open state?
3. For Box B, I'd like to plot day by day how many users are open, so I'd like to get a grouped array of users who opened and closed on each day.
4. I'd like a table over all boxes of how many users are in an open state.

For example, in SQL these would have forms something like this (not tested code, I'm hoping it's easier to use django's query language):

```
-- 1
SELECT event_type FROM Events
WHERE event_type in ('OPEN', 'CLOSE')
  AND user = U
HAVING max(event_timestamp);

-- 2
SELECT count(*) FROM (
    SELECT user, event_type FROM Events
    WHERE event_type in ('OPEN', 'CLOSE')
    GROUP BY user
    HAVING max(event_timestamp)
) as T
WHERE event_type = 'OPEN';

-- 3
// A bit complicated any way I slice it due to the
// mapping from datetime to date.

-- 4
SELECT box, count(user) FROM (
    SELECT box, user, event_type FROM Events
    WHERE event_type in ('OPEN', 'CLOSE')
    GROUP BY box, user
    HAVING max(event_timestamp)
) as T
WHERE event_type = 'OPEN'
GROUP BY box;
```

I've explained my four use cases, but I suspect once I understand one of them, the others will follow.  Clearly I've just not grokked something from the docs (I hope).

Many thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Please focus your question to a single problem, relevant documentation is here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was one problem.  As noted at the end of the question, I think the technique that solves one solves them all.  (Thanks for the subquery link, I'd missed that (or not adequately absorbed it on previous reading).)

Answer (score -1):

@jma - I am assuming- For Box B, how many events are in an open state? You mentioned Users are in an open state? But state/event_type(Open,Closed) is tied to the Events model.

```
  box = Box.objects.get(name='B') --- assuming you have a name field in Box entity

   events = Events.objects.filter(box=box,event_type='open') #queryset
   for event in events:
       #your logic here
       print(event)
```

3.For box B and user U, is the event most recently open or closed for this box?
Assuming there can be more than one event for a box B with that user U

```
  box = Box.objects.get(name='B') --- assuming you have a name field in Box entity
    user = User.objects.get(username='U') -- you can filter based on any field.
```

Also, this depends on where you want to implement this functionality. If you are using the Django view then you won't need to query the database for the user object. Since the request object has the user attribute.

```
In django view, user = request.user
    events = Events.objects.filter(box=box,user=user)
    for event in events:
         status = event.event_type
         if status=='Open':
              #do something
         elif status=='Closed':
              #do something
         else:
              #logic here
```

Also, just a suggestion

1. Model name should be singular. Event
2. If you simply name the event_type field type instead of event_type it's better. We are already in the Event model. So, we don't need to name the fields by tagging the model name as a prefix. However, I would stay away from naming a field type. I prefer category or something else. Same with event_timestamp. You can explicitly name this field to let's say to_be_held_on or created_at (based on your use case)

Comment: A user could change state multiple times: open, close, open.

Comment: @jma- State in your model definition is tied to events. Not user

Comment: Each event is about a (user, box) (at a certain time).  User U1 opening box B1 is different than U1 opening B2 or U2 opening B1.

Comment: If there are a hundred boxes, I'd maybe like to avoid 100 server round-trips to render the table of box counts.